# How to tell settings charm currently visible

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Apologize if i am wrong, I'm developing metro app using Windows 8 release preview and C#(VS 2012), I'm stuck with Settings charm.
**Brief:** In my app there are two modes Admin and user, So settings should access only to admin,
However, when the user brings out the settings charm can we get that mouse events? or Is there way to get notification from app that user is trying to open settings. Please Help me Thanks in advance

Comment: You do not have access to that information. But you don't need to. Simply don't register with the Settings charm when running in User mode.

Answer (score 0):

Raymond Chen is correct.  When your application is running in "User" mode, don't register your app with the Settings charm.  When a user is logged in as an administrator, allow the registration to happen.  Very simple solution.